# Sympy Function substitution

Tags: python, matlab, sympy, substitution

I use things like

```
x = Function('x',real=True)(t)
```

which gives `x(t)` as function variables in all my calculations. I can now differentiate with respect to time, solve (not `nonlinsolve` or `solveset`, because they cannot subs these functions) and so on.

However, I want to export my results to MATLAB. So I need the `(t)` gone. I can fill a `dict` with `d = {x(t):x}`, but I think there is a more elegant way to do this for all Functions, like `y(t),z(t)`,...

My desired result is for the input

```
expr = x(t)-y(t)
output = x-y
```

where x and y can be "Function" as known to Sympy, but there shall not be `(t)` in the output. And I do want to avoid introducing all my variables again without the dependence on time!

Comment: How are you exporting to Matlab? Is it a _string_ where you want to remove the `(t)`? Wouldn't slicing or indexing do that?

Comment: I want to avoid substitution in the final string. At that time it's expressions with `expr = x(t) - 1` character. I want the same result as: `expr.subs({x(t):x})`. Just for all Functions, like `y(t),z(t)`.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your desired result is. Please clarify.

Comment: I reformulated the whole question, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a loop that [walks through the expression tree](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#recursing-through-an-expression-tree) and replaces any function whose argument is `t` by a symbol matching the name of that function. The substitutions are made in another copy of the expression, to avoid modifying the expression we are walking through.

Example: if expr is `x(t) - y(t)`, then expr1 is `x - y`.

```
expr1 = expr
for f in preorder_traversal(expr):
  if f.args == (t,):
    expr1 = expr1.subs(f, Symbol(str(f.func)))
print(expr1)
```

Comment: This is perfect. I knew I could somehow walk the tree, but the key idea here is the "if args==(t,)" I would have definitely not know that this is even possible! Thanks!